# Создание файла в определенной директории

Tags: java, android

Делаю приложение на Android и столкнулся с проблемой. Я хочу чтобы пользователь выбрал директорию и в эту директорию скопировался файл. С извлечением файла нет проблем, но есть проблема с директорией. Мой условный dir dialog извлекает данные в качестве Uri, и когда я пытаюсь создать файл то ничего не получается т.к данные в Uri не указывают расположение нужной директории. Можно ли как-то конвертировать эти данные из Uri в обычную, условную строку по типу "/directory1/Documents/Download"?

Код открытия dir dialog

```
public void exportQuizChooseDir(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a directory"), 123);

    }
```

Код обработки данных из dir dialog

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        selectedExportDir = data.getData(); //The uri with the location of the file
    }

    }
```

Comment: Можно через кучу костылей, зависящих от приложения, в котором юзер выбрал папку и версии ОС, но ни с какими разрешениями вы не создадите в ней файл, если она не в первичной памяти (обычно встроенная в аппарат). Поэтому лучше ознакомьтесь с классами `DocumentFile` (для операций с папкой/файлами) и `ContentResolver` (для чтения/записи содержимого) и измените логику под их использование.

Comment: @woesss Я воспользовался вашими советами и файл создается. Однако есть проблемы: 1. Что нужно вписать в mimetype чтобы создавался текстовый файл с определенным расширением (допустим .ffr) 2. Данные не записываются в этот файл почему-то